# Blocking next door noise in rental apartment

Tags: noise

Any advice on cost-effective ways to block noise from a next door unit in a rental apartment? As I do not own the unit, opening the walls and adding insulation is not an option. There seems to be a thin part of the wall 2-3 meters in length where the noise passes through the most.

Looking to cover the following wall tile surface. Total length about double what is shown.

[image]

Comment: What kind of noise do you need to block?  Can you post an image of the problem wall so we can see what you have to work with?  Hanging a large, heavy rug on the wall like a tapestry could cut down the sound, especially if you put carpet padding behind it.

Comment: @fixer1234 added a photo!

Comment: And regarding what kind of noise: TV and talking